# Netsuite: How can i get the field value from tab?

Tags: netsuite

Netsuite Newbie here.
What i should do if i want to get the value of "AMOUNT INSURED" in tab Items?
I have tried something like this to get the employee email when i open a page of an employee.

```js
function emailStatus(){
  var salesRep = nlapiGetFieldValue('salesrep');
  var salesRepEmail = nlapiLookupField('employee', salesRep, 'email',true);
  alert(salesRepEmail+statusV);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot looks like a sales order or some other transaction. 'Amount Insured' also appears to be a custom field on that record.  If so, you can get the value from a 'subtab', or ‘sublist’, using `nlapiGetLineItemValue(type, fieldname, line)`.

- ‘type' is the sublist name
- ‘fieldname' is the name of the field value you want
- ‘line' is the line number on the transaction, starting with 1.

To do this, you will need the script id for that field.

To get the script ID, navigate to `Customization -> Lists, Records & Fields -> Transaction Line Fields`.  Find the field ‘Amount Insured’ and note the ID value in this list.  It will start with ‘custbody…'

With this information, you can use the following line to get the value in question:

```
var amountInsured = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'custbody_amount_insured', 1);
```

You can read more about this API in the [NetSuite help documentation here](https://tstdrv946228.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3042487.html#bridgehead_N3045409).